Firebase exception handling
How can I get a specific error from firebase authentication only thing that e.code gives me is (The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired.)
So I can declare that the error is due to a wrong password or wrong email
I tried e.message
But it didn't help either

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Catch FirebaseAuthException (not Exception or something else) and check code property against possible values, listed for auth functions in this StackOverflow answer. Also you seem to have credentials issues, so follow those instructions to set up Firebase correctly. Hope that helps
EDIT: If email enumeration protection is enabled you are unable to get wrong-password or wrong-email error codes as per this article

actually i did that already` on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
if (e.code ==
"The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired.") {
print("something went wrong");
                        }`


I edited my answer to accommodate for email enumeration protection which may be your issue
